# Flag on condition on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to do the following (in pseudo code) :

```
for each row of my dataframe;
    if the value of the cell "date" is between the values of the cells "begin" and "end", then write "1" in the cell "flag", 0 otherwise
```

I tried the following :

```
df['flag'] = 1
df['flag'] = df['flag'].apply(lambda x:x if (df['begin'] < df['date'] and df['date'] < df['end']) else 0)
# (I'm coming from R...)
```

And I get :

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous
```

I get what Python is telling me, that in the condition, it isn't comparing the contents of the cells in each row, but the whole columns.

How can I get what I want ? (The solution doesn't have to follow the same approach, I'm new to Python and here to learn)

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach df in dataframe: \n if df['begin'] < df['date'] < df['end']: \n df['flag'] = 1` (Line wrap at \n needed, but not available in comment).

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (pointing at the first `df` part)

Comment: `for` instead of `foreach` of course... sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
df['flag'] = ((df['date'] > df['begin']) & (df['date'] < df['end'])).astype(int)
```

Assuming that dates are datetime and your begin and end are datestrings this should work

The problem with this:

```
df['flag'] = df['flag'].apply(lambda x:x if (df['begin'] < df['date'] and df['date'] < df['end']) else 0)
```

firstly `if` doesn't understand how to treat a boolean array hence the error, additionally to compare multiple conditions you should use the bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `~` for `and`, `or`, and `not` respectively. Additionally due to operator precedence the multiple conditions must be enclosed in parentheses `()`

So `((df['date'] > df['begin']) & (df['date'] < df['end']))` will return a boolean Series, you can then cast the type using `astype(int)` to convert `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`

Comment: Needs a small edit, but it works, thanks. And thank you for the explanation.